# Scrapy catch error when use the proxy

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

when use scrapy to crawl web, set the proxy as below:

```
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    proxy_address = random.choice(self.proxies.keys())
    proxy_user_pass = self.proxies[proxy_address]
    request.meta['proxy'] = proxy_address
    basic_auth = 'Basic ' + base64.encodestring(proxy_user_pass)
    request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = basic_auth
```

and I catch the 
**error:**

```
Error downloading <GET http://www.MySpider.com/>:    
twisted.python.failure.Failure class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'
```

and without setting proxy, it can run correctly.

Comment: this could be a timeout problem on your proxy, can you try using a different one?